# Error with Entity Framework .Any() filter

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

**Here's my query:**

```
var x = db
   .Users
   .Where(u => u.Locations.Any(l => searchedLocation.Counties.Any(c => c.LocationId == l.LocationId));
```

**Context:**

- `Users` is `IQueryable<User>`. (EF object set)
- `searchedLocation` is a `Location` object.
- `Counties` is a `ICollection<MiniLocation>`.

**What i'm trying to do:**

> Return all users, where any of the Counties for those locations have a locationId of any of the counties belonging to the searched location.

**Example:**

Search for New York City (LocationId = 1. County1LocationId = 2)

User: Bob. Locations: Soho. County1LocationId = 2. County2 LocationId = 3.

So that's a match. (because Soho have a County with a LocationId of 2, and so does NYC)

**Error i receive:**

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'xxx.xxx.Locations.MiniLocation'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx#RefNonScalarClosures) states that this construct is not supported. You can use [this method](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx) for .Net 3.5 Linq to Entities to help replace the use of `Any`.

Comment: Im on .NET 4. Okay so i understand the error, but not the solution proposed in the link you provided. Any further advice/examples?

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a list of the location ID can be searched.

```
var idsToSearch = "1,2,3,4,5...";
```

Then you can use `Contains` in the following way:

```
var x = db
       .Users
       .Where(u => idsToSearch.Contains(u.LocationId));
```

Comment: i dont think that's right. first of all, `.Contains` only takes `T` or `IEnumerable<T>`. Secondly, that would only match where any of the counties contains the location id of the searched location, whereas i want where any of the counties contains any of the searched locations counties. Complicated, i know. :)